# How to create lambda of type ((KeyboardEvent) -> dynamic)? in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, dynamic, lambda, kotlin-js

I want to listen keyboard events. So I set lambda to `document.onkeypress`, which should be of type:

```
var onkeypress: ((KeyboardEvent) -> dynamic)?
```

Currently I'm getting this:
[image]

Lambda should return dynamic type, and I do return it, don't understand what's wrong with this construction.

Comment: What UI system are you using? I don't recognize classes like `KeyboardEvent` and `dynamic`, which is weirdly not capitalized. Can you show these classes? Evidently `Keyboard.asDynamic()` does not return a `dynamic` instance.

Comment: It is Kotlin js, org.w3c.dom.events.KeyboardEvent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you have found the answer on [Kotlin forum](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-to-create-lambda-of-type-keyboardevent-dynamic/15821/4)

```
window.onload = {
        document.onkeypress = { event: KeyboardEvent ->
            // Do work
            Unit
        }
        Unit
    }
```

Comment: The problem in my first code is that window.onload lambda require return expression of some object. But assigning is not an expression in kotlin. So we need to return some object (Unit) at the end of the lambda block.